# Getting exception whenever try to add the same item i deleted in flutter

Tags: flutter

Using Dismissible i am removing the item that listed through textfiled, but whenever i try to add the same item i deleted its showing exception. can anyone know how solve this?

Inside setState method i tried all the possible things, but getting same exception.

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView(
    children: _dEntry/*.reversed*/.map((data) {
      return Dismissible(
        key: Key(data),
        onDismissed: (direction){
          setState(() {
            data.removeWhere();
          });},
        background: Container(color: Colors.blue),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(data),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/flutter-dev/attach/d6883328e4019/Screenshot_1562852907.png?part=0.1&authuser=0&view=1


//this error message i am getting

Answer (score 1):

You have to create unique key for each `Dismissible`. Here is one of solutions:

```
int _dismissibleKey = 0;
...
Dismissible(
    key: ObjectKey(_dismissibleKey++), ... )
```

Comment: how can i provide string values using int var.

Answer (score 0):

`key: Key(data),` the data is not unique, you if your list data contains an id or something which is unique throw-out the list use that.

```
child: ListView(
            children: _dEntry/*.reversed*/.map((data) {
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(data), // <--- this data var is not unique for the app.
```

for example what @andrew suggested or like so.

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _listKey = GlobalKey(); // <-- add this under the class declaration

child: ListView(
            children: _dEntry/*.reversed*/.map((data) {
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(_listKey ), // <--- change this
```

by using a `GlobalKey` you are able to build unique value for the key

Comment: is it require to make any changes in onDismissed

Comment: no you just need a global key for the key on Dismissable